# Is there a physical interpretation of norms greater than L2?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, geometric-interpretation

In case anyone is confused about the terminology, here's where I'm pulling it from:

http://blog.christianperone.com/2011/10/machine-learning-text-feature-extraction-tf-idf-part-ii/

To summarize the relevant part: an L$n$ norm is a notion of distance given by raising each distance component to the $n$th power, summing them, and then taking the $n$th root.

For L1, this simply means to add the components, and it is known as taxicab distance, with physical significance when navigating a grid. For L2, this is the Euclidean distance formula we learned in high school, with obvious physical significance.

What about higher-level norms, though? Is there any physical interpretation of L3, L4, etc., let alone a direct, physical application?

Comment: [Hypercontractivity inequalities](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/boolean-analysis/lecture16.pdf) (does that count?). Also, the $L_\infty$ norm, if you allow the limiting norm for $n=\infty$, has a pretty natural interpretation.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ineO1tIyPfM&t=528s  does this help ?